# Extract Data from API in ADF

Tags: json, azure, rest, azure-data-factory

I need to extract data from REST API in ADF, which I am doing using WEB activity and COPY activity.

When used Web activity, I am getting extra `\` in response as below.

```
{
    "Response": "[{\"Name\":\"Countries\",\"Url\":\"/api/Datab/abc\",\"Trees\":[{\"Name\":\"Economics Locations\"},{\"Name\":\"Economics Indicators\"}]},{\"Name\":\"Global\",\"Url\":\"/api/Datab/def\",\"DatabankCode\":\"WDMacro\",\"StartYear\":1980,\"EndYear\":2050,\"HasQuarterlyData\":true,\"Trees\":[{\"Name\":\"Global Economics Locations\"},{\"Name\":\"Global Economics Indicators\"}]}]",
    "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Rate-Limit-60": "Unthrottled (0/60 requests) in 60 sec window",
        "Rate-Limit-60-Status": "Unthrottled",
        "Rate-Limit-60-Window": "60",
        "Rate-Limit-60-RequestCount": "0",
        "Rate-Limit-60-RequestLimit": "60",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Date": "Mon, 20 Feb 2023 11:32:52 GMT",
        "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
        "X-AspNet-Version": "4.0.30319",
        "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
        "Content-Length": "17782",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Expires": "-1"
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (West Europe)",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I Used COPY activities(created REST DS and Linked service), I got below issue, I am assuming this is because of `\` .
[image]

Can someone please help me,

1. How to get rid of `\` in response of WEB activity output?
2. How to make COPY activity WORK, So I can sink to Storage account?
3. I need to make another API call for each `Url` of Response?
   As in this output, How do I parse `Url` to capture `/api/Datab/abc` and `/api/Datab/def`

Comment: Is your API Returnig data into json format correctly?

Comment: I assume it is returning correctly

Comment: rest Api is returning deserializing array error its because of invalid json data

Comment: not sure what you mean by deserialize, but I am able to parse json (tried online json parsers) , after replacing \  in WEB activity output response.

Comment: @PratikLad
Parsing failed, When I copy response directly https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFai1.png
Parsing succeded when I replaced \ https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQnAM.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the similar issue and got similar response with extra `slash(\)`

[image]

Then I took set variable activity and created **array** variable with name `demo`  and converted it into Json format.

```
@json(activity('Web1').output.Response)
```

[image]

this will give you correct format of array.

[image]

Then pass this array variable to Foreach activity as below.

[image]

To access Url from this variable in foreach activity use `@item().Url`

[image]

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Pratik, working as expected. BTW, can you please let me know, how did you manage to get similar output?

Comment: I just inserted your response in json file in blob storage so it will take it as string.